# symfony 3.4 loses session after login redirect

Tags: php, symfony

I have problem with Symfony 3.4 and login site. If I stoped code before redirect:

```
#LoginController
public function loginAction(Request $request) {

    [.........]

    dump($this->getUser());
    exit();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

object User is created and session data is stored in /var/session/dev.

But if I stopped code after redirect at the beginning of index method object user is null.

```
#DefaultController
public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    dump($this->getUser());
    exit();

    [.........]
}
```

Theoretically I was logged but after redirect site back to login view.

I copied this project 1 to 1 from computer where site works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Project works on php 7.4, but installation required max 7.2. Strange but works.